# How to repeat values until certain year in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have data where the variable **X** provides information for certain years: 2003, 2007, 2011, 2015 and 2019.

For example, for a country A in 2003 the X is =10. In 2007 the X is =20; and then again in 2011 X is =30.

What I want is to fill the years from 2003 to 2006 with X=10. And then from 2007 to 2010, X=20, and so on.In other words, the latest value should be applied to all the coming years until new value.

I simply can't figure this out and I've recently taken a course in R. The only way that I can think of is to 1) create manually all the missing years in-between and 2) use this function

```
fill after <- function(idx, k) sapply(1:length(idx), function(x) +any(idx[(pmax(x - k, 1)):x] %in% 1))
```

But I feel that I've no idea of where I'm going with this.

Here's a 50 random observations from my data:

```r
dput(mydata)
structure(list(ccode = c(373, 130, 372, 0, 616, 90, 830, 651, 
920, 701, 900, 360, 130, 560, 155, 439, 343, 510, 484, 615, 451, 
40, 471, 0, 135, 434, 255, 235, 220, 58, 2, 433, 0, 155, 600, 
390, 600, 625, 780, 317, 360, 0, 325, 790, 290, 770, 230, 452, 
0, 0), year = c(2019L, 2007L, 2015L, 2015L, 2011L, 2003L, 2007L, 
2011L, 2015L, 2011L, 2003L, 2015L, 2011L, 2007L, 2019L, 2007L, 
2007L, 2003L, 2019L, 2015L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2015L, 
2007L, 2011L, 2003L, 2003L, 2019L, 2011L, 2015L, 2007L, 2003L, 
2015L, 2007L, 2003L, 2011L, 2011L, 2007L, 2003L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2007L, 2015L, 2003L, 2011L, 2019L), cname = c("Azerbaijan", 
"Ecuador", "Georgia", "Martinique", "Tunisia", "Guatemala", "Singapore", 
"Egypt", "New Zealand", "Turkmenistan", "Australia", "Romania", 
"Ecuador", "SouthAfrica", "Chile", "BurkinaFaso", "Macedonia", 
"TanzaniaUR", "Congo Brazzaville", "Algeria", "SierraLeone", 
"Cuba", "Cameroon", "Aruba", "Peru", "Benin", "Germany", "Portugal", 
"France", "Antigua-Barbuda", "USA", "Senegal", "NethAntilles", 
"Chile", "Morocco", "Denmark", "Morocco", "Sudan", "SriLanka", 
"Slovakia", "Romania", "Cook Is", "Italy", "Nepal", "Poland", 
"Pakistan", "Spain", "Ghana", "HongKong", "Cook Is"), X = c(0L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 5L, 0L, 28L, 1L, 1L, 18L, 3L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 9L, 0L, 16L, 5L, 124L, 1L, 99L, 0L, 552L, 
13L, 0L, 4L, 7L, 36L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 12L, 2L, 1L, 51L, 12L, 4L, 
0L, 12L, 3L, 1L, 2L)), datalabel = "", time.stamp = "11 Jan 2021 14:51", formats = c("%9.0g", 
"%8.0g", "%20s", "%8.0g"), types = c(65527L, 65529L, 20L, 65529L
), val.labels = structure(c("", "", "", ""), .Names = c("", "", 
"", "")), var.labels = c("", "", "", ""), version = 118L, label.table = list(), expansion.fields = list(), byteorder = "LSF", orig.dim = c(569L, 
4L), row.names = c(31L, 147L, 186L, 315L, 520L, 203L, 447L, 155L, 
360L, 525L, 20L, 420L, 148L, 461L, 91L, 71L, 300L, 501L, 102L, 
1L, 443L, 120L, 76L, 19L, 391L, 51L, 190L, 410L, 180L, 6L, 554L, 
432L, 354L, 89L, 336L, 139L, 338L, 480L, 472L, 449L, 419L, 109L, 
247L, 349L, 404L, 381L, 465L, 197L, 219L, 108L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: (FYI, I edited your question to better format the sample data. Thank you for providing it in that format! The advantage of `dput` is that it is completely unambiguous ... the disadvantage of you prepending `>` on every row is that it made it harder for us to just copy and paste into our console. On Stack sites, it's typically better to put code and raw data within a [code block](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) as I've done here. Thanks.)

Comment: thanks, this was useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the `tidyr` functions `expand` and `fill` will be helpful here.

Try something like this:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

mydata %>% 
  # expand all years by country
  group_by(cname, ccode) %>% 
  expand(cname, ccode, year = full_seq(year, 1)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  # join with original data to get X values
  left_join(mydata) %>% 
  # fill the missing X
  fill(X)
```

This seems to work using your example data, for example "Cook Is" looks like:

```
27           Cook Is     0 2015   1
28           Cook Is     0 2016   1
29           Cook Is     0 2017   1
30           Cook Is     0 2018   1
31           Cook Is     0 2019   2
```

but you should check the result on the full dataset.